# Power BI: Refresh error with API in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, get, refresh

Here I am again with problems in API amd Power BI.

So, I have this API working in Power BI Desktop, but when I try to make it work as a flow or schedule an automatic refresh, I get the following error:

[image: Error saving Data Flow]

(Unable to save data stream
One or more tables reference a dynamic data source.
OK)

I've tried a few things, such as using `RelativePath` and changing the `QueryString`, but I still receive this message. Is there a way to make this API work?

Below is the code:

```
let
  url = url_api,
  cabecalho = [
                #"Accept"= "application/json", 
                #"Authorization"="Bearer " & Token
            ],
  FilterCriteriaAPI = [
                page = "1",
                pub_date_after = "2023-07-17",
                pub_date_before = "2023-07-18"
            ],
  queryStringAPI = Uri.BuildQueryString(FilterCriteriaAPI),
  urlCompletaAPI = url & "?" & queryStringAPI,
  responseAPI = Json.Document(Web.Contents(urlCompletaAPI, [Headers = cabecalho])),
  resultado = responseAPI[results],
  #"Converter em tabela" = Table.FromValue(resultado),
  #"Transformar colunas" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converter em tabela", {{"Value", type text}}),
  #"Substituir erros" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Transformar colunas", {{"Value", null}})
in
  #"Substituir erros"
```

I've tried

```
responseAPI = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [RelativePath = queryStringAPI, Query = q[  [Headers = cabecalho]]]))
```

And

```
urlCompletaAPI = url & "?" & FilterCriteria,
  responseAPI = Json.Document(Web.Contents(urlCompletaAPI, [Headers = cabecalho])),
```